# Is there a solution for the map function not properly checking the elements from updated array (of cart) in my react-redux and redux toolkit store?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I add product to the cart from Products  and product gets added to the cart (as each product increases length of array), but when rendering the updated cart from Cart component, it doesn't render properly and console keeps giving error "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Cart`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
div".

I did various methods to go over the solution, but just figured out probably the product element's (from productsinCart array) payload is coming as undefined that is what giving problem, but I may be wrong here.

Any suggestions to solve the problem?

**cartSlice.js**

```
 import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: [],

  reducers: {
    add(state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    remove(state, action) {
      state.splice(action.payload, 1);
    },
  },
});
`
export const { add, remove } = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import cartReducer from "./Slices/cartSlice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    cart: cartReducer,
  },
});

export default store;
```

**Products.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { add } from "../store/Slices/cartSlice";

const Products = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products";

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);

        const result = await response.json();
        

        setProducts(result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Sorry, there is an error");
      }
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const handleAdd = (product) => {
    dispatch(add(product));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {products?.map((product) => {
        const { id, image, price, title } = product;

        return (
          <div key={id}>
            <img src={image} alt="" />
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <h5>{price}</h5>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                handleAdd(add());
              }}
              
            >
              Add to Cart
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

**Cart.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout";

const Cart = () => {
  const productsinCart = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.cart;
  });

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h3>Cart </h3>
      <section>
        <div>
          {productsinCart?.map((product) => {           
            const { id, image, price, title } = product;
            
            return (
              <div key={id}>
                <img src={image} alt="" />
                <p>{title}</p>
                <p>{price}</p>
                <button>Remove</button>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </section>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Note: I only tried adding the product and rendering the updated cart.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The `Products` component is not correctly adding products to `state.cart`. Instead of passing the currently mapped product object to the `handleAdd` callback, it's invoking the `add` action sans any payload and passing the result.

```
const Products = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products";

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const result = await response.json();
        setProducts(result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Sorry, there is an error");
      }
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const handleAdd = (product) => {
    dispatch(add(product));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {products?.map((product) => {
        const { id, image, price, title } = product;

        return (
          <div key={id}>
            <img src={image} alt="" />
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <h5>{price}</h5>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                handleAdd(add()); // <-- passing action object
              }}
            >
              Add to Cart
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

So instead of having a cart array that looks like:

```js
[
  { id: "...", image: "...", price: "...", title: "..." },
  { id: "...", image: "...", price: "...", title: "..." },
  { id: "...", image: "...", price: "...", title: "..." },
  ...etc
]
```

You have a cart array that likely looks like:

```js
[
  {
    type: "cart/add",
    payload: { type: "cart/add", payload: undefined }
  },
  {
    type: "cart/add",
    payload: { type: "cart/add", payload: undefined }
  },
  {
    type: "cart/add",
    payload: { type: "cart/add", payload: undefined }
  },
  ...etc
]
```

All these cart array elements are missing the product properties, including the `id` property that is used as a React key.

## Solution

The fix is trivial, pass the `product` to the `handleAdd` handler.

```
const handleAdd = (product) => {
  dispatch(add(product));
};

return (
  <div>
    {products.map((product) => {
      const { id, image, price, title } = product;

      return (
        <div key={id}>
          <img src={image} alt="product" />
          <h4>{title}</h4>
          <h5>{price}</h5>
          <button onClick={() => handleAdd(product)}>
            Add to Cart
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```